# Problema con el php.ini

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un servidor en Debian, necesito habilitar las extensiones

```
php_pdo_mysql 
php_pdo
```

He visto que tengo varios archivos php.ini, al parecer el servidor tiene instalado zendserver. Ejecute `php --ini` y me aparece:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, 
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mssql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo-dblib.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

Sin embargo en mi pagina phpinfo() me muestra que el arcivo php.ini en uso es otro.

```
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini
```

http://www.municomas.gob.pe/phpinfo.php

Comment: una cosa es el PHP que levante Apache otra cosas es el PHP de tu sistema operativo; debes tener instalado dos PHP y busca en /usr/bin php debe tener un link simbolico actualizado por el tuyo

Comment: Entonces? Cual de ambos php.ini es el que me permite habilitar las extenesiones PDF para mysql?

Comment: si quierers configurar tu php de apache debe ser este /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini